# Java awt GraphicsDevice TYPE_PRINTER?

Tags: java, printing, awt, printers, screens

Not that I absolutely need this answered for something, but I'm curious as to why there's a TYPE_PRINTER for a java.awt.GraphicsDevice. I'm assuming that's referring to a printer like for printing paper as the javadoc just says "Device is a printer". Not that I think it couldn't be used in this context, but I guess I'm thinking about it more as an IO device. Is this mainly meant for printers that have some sort of display screen (aka not the one I'm looking at next to me which just has status lights)? Otherwise I'm not seeing a reason to use java.awt.Menu or anything else interactive with printing to paper.